# How to call a jar applet file in html

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I have copied a very simple applet (just a written message) in java and created a jar file. I called the jar file with the following code but when I opened the file in a browser nothing's appearing (apart from the header). What beginners mistake am I making?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        Chess App
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet code="Main.class" archive="JavaChessGradeApplet.jar" width=640 height=480></applet>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Not. All the major browsers stopped supporting applets years ago. applets are dead and burried, there's no use in still using them.

Comment: @Stultuske gutting - I've written a larger program on Java and want to get it online. What's the best way to go about doing it?

Comment: did you write it as a rest/soap service? just upload it to a server, and create a UI. the UI doesn't have to be in Java, doesn't mean it can't be